# jQuery - Add CSS border to an image in atextarea

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

I work with `TinyIMCE` and I would like add a border to all image in the `textarea` when user submit the form.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
 var textareaContent = $("#edit-message1-value").val();
 // And then I would like handle the textareaContent (it's an html content)
 textareaContent.find("img")...
 // or
 $(textareaContent).find("img")...
 ...
 })
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is this really a `<textarea>` element? Because they shouldn't contain any other HTML elements (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea img').css('border', '1px solid #FF000');
```

it will add a border red to all images inside a textarea (you can change the element)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the solution : add  tags before and after textarea value

```
var textareaHtml = $('<div>' + $("#edit-message1-value").val() + '</div>');

  // Update each image style
  $.each(textareaHtml.find("img"), function() {
if ($(this).css("border") != "3px solid rgb(99, 99, 99)") {
  if ($(this).attr("style")) {
    $(this).attr("style", $(this).attr("style") + " border:3px solid rgb(99, 99, 99);");
  } else {
    $(this).attr("style", "border:3px solid rgb(99, 99, 99);");
  }
}
  });

  // Update textarea content
  $("#edit-message1-value").val(textareaHtml.html());
```